# Accessing a StaticItemTemplate control from a MenuItem

Tags: asp.net, menuitem

I've written the following menu:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">  
  <Items>  
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="javascript:SetRoadMap();" Text="Road Map" Value="SetRoadMap"/>  
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="javascript:SetHybridMap();" Text="Hybrid Map" Value="SetHybridMap" />  
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="javascript:SearchAddress(document.getElementById('addressToSearch').text);" Text="Search Address" Value="searchAddress" />  
  </Items>  
  <StaticItemTemplate>  
    <asp:Label runat="server" Height="20px" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>' />  
    <asp:TextBox ID="addressToSearch" runat="server" Height="15px" Width="250px" Visible='<%# ((string)Eval("Value") == "searchAddress") %>' />  
  </StaticItemTemplate>  
</asp:Menu>
```

The SearchAddress menu item's URL can't seems to find the text box (id 'addressToSearch') attached to it.

Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish. If you want the ID of the addressToSearch box to remain static, you can add this to the Textbox control -  ClientIDMode="Static".

Comment: I'm trying to pass the address entered into 'addresstoSearch' to the SearchAddress function. I've tried setting the control to static but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">  
  <Items>  
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="javascript:SetRoadMap();" Text="Road Map" Value="SetRoadMap"/>  
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="javascript:SetHybridMap();" Text="Hybrid Map" Value="SetHybridMap" />  
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="javascript:SearchAddress(document.getElementById('addressToSearch').text);" Text="Search Address" Value="searchAddress" />  
  </Items>  
  <StaticItemTemplate>  
    <asp:Label runat="server" Height="20px" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>' />  
    <asp:TextBox ID="addressToSearch" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Height="15px" Width="250px" Visible='<%# ((string)Eval("Value") == "searchAddress") %>' />  
  </StaticItemTemplate>  
</asp:Menu>
```

I should have added the ClientIDMode property and looked for *Value* instead of *Text*.